# c++ metro app with C# library build error WMC1006

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am just starting a metro app. The main application is a c++ metro app. The application builds and runs fine.

I have a c# library added to the solution and it builds everything builds fine.

I reference the C# library from the C++ application and it will not build with the following errors:

> error WMC1006: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'
>
> error EMC9999: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtim, Version.....................

Any ideas what's going on? I have not added any references to my c# class library. It's a vanilla metro library.

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: Is your C# library set to output a windows metadata file (WINMD) (as opposed to a .NET class library)?

Comment: it is set to output a Class library

Comment: So, have you tried changing that to output a WINMD file?

Comment: yes, and that worked, although there are a lot of extra restrictions on the code for it to work. Some of them seem lame, like no property can be a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as Kris Vandermotten points out, C++/CX cannot consume C# class libraries (only WinMD files), and there are many restrictions on WinMD files that do not exist for managed class libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my app and was getting the same errors

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'
>
> Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime

My app is a mixed C#/C++ Windows Store app where the main project is C#. I'm using VS 2012 Pro.

My problems came from deleting .net SDKs from the system when I was attempting to resolve a different issue.

The solution for me was running (in an admin command prompt)

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

and then doing a repair (Programs and Features -> Change -> Repair) on my Visual Studio 2012 Professional installation.

These were the only steps that allowed me to build the app again.